# Cryptic React error "unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been able to find limited information on this error and was hoping someone could take a deep dive into explaining exactly what causes this.  I haven't changed any of the code that appears to be showing up in the call stack recently, so I was wondering if this is from a newer update?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case, The error/warning was casued by the [react-block-ui](https://availity.github.io/react-block-ui/) package. Currently there is an [opened issue](https://github.com/Availity/react-block-ui/issues/40) at github of that package. The issue hasn't been solved so far.

It's a react issue. You can check if any third-party-packages are causing this. You can check [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/c80678c7606b1895573c23182bfb9a418e2ad31e/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberWorkLoop.js#L605-L607) to see exactly where the error is coming from. I found these comments from there -

```
// We're already rendering, so we can't synchronously flush pending work.
// This is probably a nested event dispatch triggered by a lifecycle/effect,
// like `el.focus()`. Exit.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I no longer have access to the code base this was in, but we were definitely using ```el.focus()``` extensively in our code.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 5):

My problem was putting the `debugger` inside the code. As soon as I removed it, the error went away. So just in case

[image]

Comment: Even I have faced this issue while debugging React code and placing debuggers.

Answer (score 2):

I spent quite some time debugging a similar issue on my project. In the end, we were calling `focus` inside a `setState` function, but this can be quite hidden by callbacks. In our case this was looking at this:

```js
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  func() {
    this.setState(state => {
      // ... Doing something
      this.props.onStateChange();
      // ... Returning some state
    });
  }
}
```

And then elsewhere:

```js
  onStateChange = () => {
    this.element.focus();
  };

  render() {
    return <ChildComponent onStateChange={this.onStateChange} />;
  }
```

I solved the problem by calling the callback in `componentDidUpdate`:

```js
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  func() {
    this.setState(state => {
      // ... Doing something
      // ... Returning some state
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (compare(prevState, this.state)) {
      this.props.onStateChange();
    }
  }
}
```

Another possible solution: A colleague of mine also suggested to use `requestAnimationFrame` inside `setState` so that the call would be happening out of the render cycle.

Hope this will help some people coming here!